# NaN, when running BMI calculator

Tags: javascript, html

What am i doing wrong? According to the textbook example this is supposed to be sufficient code, but I get NaN when running it in a browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en"> 
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>test</title>
      </head>
    <body>

    <p>Vekt: <input type="text" id="txtVekt" /></p>
    <p>Hoyde: <input type="text" id="txtHoyde" /></p>
      <button id="btnBeregn">Beregn</button>
      <p id="resultat"></p>

      <script>
    window.onload = beregn();


      function beregn(){
        var hoyde = document.getElementById("txtHoyde").value;
        var vekt = document.getElementById("txtVekt").value;

        var bmi = vekt / (hoyde * vekt);

        document.getElementById("resultat").innerHTML = "Din BMI er: " + bmi;
      }

    </script>

      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Well, what do you expect `document.getElementById("txtHoyde").value` to return right after the page has loaded? From what I can see, there is no value. If I take no value and perform math on it then surely the result must be NotANumber.

Comment: your initial values in the textboxes default to 0 so your `vekt / (hoyde * vekt)` is dividing by 0

Comment: The window onload events trigger upon site load, so when the user opens the site. At that point (I assume, the text inputs are empty). Also, if you do it like this, the function beregnen will be executed immediatly. In addition, you need to parse the values of the text inputs with parseFloat (or something similar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your values are not initialized when you first run the function
2. There's really no need to run the function `onload`, especially
   since your values aren't initialized.  Note that my code removes the `onload` invocation.

You can just run the calculation when the button is clicked.  You might also want to add some validation before you run the function, but I'll leave that exercise to you.

```
  <body>
 <p>Vekt: <input type="text" id="txtVekt" /></p>
    <p>Hoyde: <input type="text" id="txtHoyde" /></p>
      <button id="btnBeregn" onclick="beregn();" >Beregn</button>
      <p id="resultat"></p>

      <script>
      function beregn(){
        var hoyde = document.getElementById("txtHoyde").value;
        var vekt = document.getElementById("txtVekt").value;

        //this assumes your inputs are valid numbers...
        var bmi = vekt / (hoyde * vekt);

        document.getElementById("resultat").innerHTML = "Din BMI er: " + bmi;
      }

    </script>

   </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

`hoyde` and `vekt` do not have any value when the page loads since the inputs are empty, so there is no reason why `bmi` should give you anything other than `NaN`.

You need to either give those inputs a default value (probably 1 to begin) and then rerun the `begregn` function whenever the button is clicked:

```
 <p>Vekt: <input type="text" id="txtVekt" value=1/></p>
 <p>Hoyde: <input type="text" id="txtHoyde" value=1/></p>
 <button id="btnBeregn" onclick="begregn()">Beregn</button>
```

Or just don't run `begregn` on window load, but only when the button is clicked

Comment: :P. I saw the "0" sample values and almost thought to respond, but then you changed them.... awe, to bad :D.

Comment: haha I wrote the answer too quickly but luckily caught myself

Comment: I'm downvoting your answer due to the use of the `onclick` attribute. You got it 90% right. What you should do is use `window.onload = function(){ document.getElementById('btnBegregn').onclick = begregn; };`. @Marc answer has the same problem. I'm using the `onclick` property for compatibility with IE<8.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I don't think that deserves a downvote for either of us. The solution is correct and compatible with all modern browsers. Had the OP asked for something compatible with IE<8 then sure downvote me for not answering his question, but otherwise your comment makes no sense

Comment: It still isn't the recommended way. The recommended way is `document.getElementById('btnBegregn').addEventListener('click', begregn);`.

Comment: recommended by whom? `addEventListener` doesn't even work in IE 8 and down as you need to use `attachEvent`. I don't know where you're getting your info but your argument is not even correct:

 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

And here is a pretty comprehensive answer showing why one is not better than the other:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/6348597/1148244

Answer (score 0):

window.onload runs... on window load. :)

Change `window.onload = beregn();` to:

`var btn = document.getElementById("btnBeregn");
btn.addEventListener("click", beregn);`